# PHP/JS - pass values with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of a textbox without pass through form actions (because i cannot neither redirect to another page or refresh the current one).

**index.php**

into head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
       $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "script.php",
       data: {
              fname: document.getElementById("fname").value,
              lname: document.getElementById("lname").value
             },
       success: function callScriptAndReturnAlert() {
                     var sdata = new XMLHttpRequest();
                     sdata.onload = function() {
                        alert(this.responseText);
                     };
                     sdata.open("get", "script.php", true);
                     sdata.send();
                  } 
              });
        }
    </script>
```

into body

```
<button class="myclass" onclick="send();">MyButton</button>
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First name here" />
<input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last name here" />
```

Button is before input just for UI stuffs

**script.php**

```
    $prev = $_SESSION['prev'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];

    [....do something....]

    echo 'You used '.$fname.' and '.$lname;
```

Well.. the script.php doesnt receive the value of the inputs fname and lname.

Comment: I do get the values. Is this all the code? Didn't you include jQuery? It works if you include it. Why do you do a second ajax call when the first call to script.php completes? And why don't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make two ajax calls when you only need one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
      $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: "script.php",
       data: {
              fname: $("#fname").val(),
              lname: $("#lname").val()
             },
       beforeSend: function(){
           alert('Sending');
       },
       success: function(data) {
              //Received data from PHP script
              alert(data);
       },
       error: function(){
           alert('Error !');
       },
       complete: function(){
           alert('Done');
       }  
     });
   }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(
    'script.php', // Your PHP file
    { // The data to pass
        'fname' : $('#fname').val(),
        'lname' : $('#lname').val()
    }
).done(function(data) { // Here your AJAX already finished correctly.
    alert(data); // Show what the PHP script returned
});
```

The `$.ajax()`, `$.get()` and `$.post()` jQuery methods **are for making AJAX calls** and, due to that, they **already manage their own XMLHttpRequest** object.